# Google Maps AP v3 I - trying to add markers dynamically with jQuery $.ajax

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Maps API v3 to create a map for my application to show viewers on our Webcast. The idea is to add a new marker on the map when a new viewer jumps onto the stream. That is the map is not reloaded, only a new marker is added.

I am trying to accomplish this with an ajax call to a script that gets the current viewers. I have an output to the console to show the results, and the latitude and longitude coordinates are correct, so I don't know why it does not put the marker onto the map.

I am referencing the same class in the page with the map as I am with the ajax script call, so I can do a PHP foreach loop in the middle of the javascript on the page and it puts the marker onto the map! But, of course, I need to use ajax to get new serverside info (new viewers).

**js with php foreach() (works)**

*note: this is how I tested it, it is in $.ajax success function, but has nothing to do with the ajax script*

```
//add markers
function addMarker(stream_id) {
  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '../../stream/' + stream_id + '/mapmarkers',
    success: function(result) {
      <?php foreach($stream_viewer_info as $viewer) : ?>

        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?= $viewer['location_info']['latitude'] . ', ' . $viewer['location_info']['longitude']; ?>),
          map: map
        }));

      <?php endforeach; ?>

    },
    complete: function() {
      setTimeout(function(){addMarker(<?=$stream_id; ?>)}, 1000);
    }


  });
}
```

**js with js for() (does not work)**

```
//add markers
function addMarker(stream_id) {
  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '../../stream/' + stream_id + '/mapmarkers',
    success: function(result) {
      for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          console.log('result ' + i + ': ' + result[i]['latitude'] + ', ' + result[i]['longitude']);

        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(result[i]['latitude'] + ', ' + result[i]['longitude']),
          map: map
        }));

      }

    },
    complete: function() {
      setTimeout(function(){addMarker(<?=$stream_id; ?>)}, 1000);
    }


  });
}
```

Comment: Do you see any errors on console? what is the output of `console.log(result)`?

Comment: @koala_dev No errors. The output of the console is
`result 0: 26.122299194336, 26.122299194336`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(result[i]['latitude'], result[i]['longitude']),
    map: map
}));
```

You need to separate the arguments by an actual comma, not a string

Comment: That makes sense, and when I try it I get a different result. Half good, half bad. The markers shows on the map now, but what should be a marker in Ft. Lauderdale, FL (US) is a marker in Egypt. So that works to put the marker on the map, but it must receive a different lat and long?

Comment: well you have the values in your console, test with those and determine if the ajax result is giving the right coordinates

Comment: The longitude is incorrect. [Egypt](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=27.702984,29.769287&hl=en&num=1&t=m&z=6) [Ft. Lauderdale FL](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=26.115986,-80.147038&hl=en&num=1&t=m&z=12), perhaps you are using the same number for latitude and longitude?

Comment: @geocodezip that seems to be the case, from the comment in the question, both values are the same

Comment: Yes. I looked up the coordinates, and they do point to Egypt. My PHP example gave the correct coordinates, but my ajax example does not. I'll have to look into this to see why.

Comment: Funny that I didn't notice that.

Comment: `if(!empty($stream_viewer_info)) {
  $i = 0;
  foreach($stream_viewer_info as $viewer) {
    $i++;
    $latitude = $viewer['location_info']['latitude'];
    $longitude = $viewer['location_info']['latitude'];
    $city = $viewer['location_info']['city'];
    $region = $viewer['location_info']['region'];

    $markers[] = array('latitude' => $latitude, 'longitude' => $longitude, 'city' => $city, 'region' => $region);
  }

  echo json_encode($markers);
}`

Comment: @nitsuj please update your question, code in comments can't be formatted

Comment: LOL. As usual, it is a typo. I assigned to `$longitude` and `$latitude` the same `$viewer[location_info']['latitude']`

Comment: @nitsuj happens to the best of us, but at least you've sorted things out, good luck with your project :)